# How to get brackets value from a document / string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the value inside the brackets of a string.
for example:

```
const mystring = "I am a {job} and my name is {name}. my age is {age} years old"
```

how am I be able to get the value inside the brackets (`job`, `age` and `name`)?

I actually use doctemplater npm to fill data to my document template. But since the template will vary,  I need to know which value is required to be inserted the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex

```js
const mystring =
  "I am a {job} and my name is {name}. my age is {age} years old";

const regex = /[^{\}]+(?=})/g;
console.log(mystring.match(regex));
```

Comment: will give wrong output if opening bracket ` {` is missing eg. `mystring = "I am job} and my {name}"`

Comment: Output will be : `["I am job", "name"]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a **lookahead**:

```js
const mystring = "I am a {job} and my name is {name}. my age is {age} years old"
console.log(mystring.match(/(?<=\{).*?(?=\})/igm))
```

Let's break it down:

- (?<=\{) - negative **lookbehind** to not include **{**
- .*? - non-greedy mode
- (?=\}) - positive **lookahead** to not include **}**